# Shalosh Klipos Hatme'os

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

What are the 3 tamei klipos, my question isn't what they are as a whole (what they represent), rather like a list, what are the three?

Answer (score 1):

The 3 impure klippos are

1. רוח סערה stormy wind
2. ענן גדול huge cloud
3. אש מתלקחת flashing fire.

These come from this passuk

וָאֵ֡רֶא וְהִנֵּה֩ ר֨וּחַ סְעָרָ֜ה בָּאָ֣ה מִן־הַצָּפ֗וֹן עָנָ֤ן גָּדוֹל֙ וְאֵ֣שׁ מִתְלַקַּ֔חַת וְנֹ֥גַֽהּ ל֖וֹ סָבִ֑יב וּמִ֨תּוֹכָ֔הּ כְּעֵ֥ין הַחַשְׁמַ֖ל מִתּ֥וֹךְ הָאֵֽשׁ׃
I looked, and lo, a stormy wind came sweeping out of the north—a huge cloud and flashing fire, surrounded by a radiance; and in the center of it, in the center of the fire, a gleam as of amber.
https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.1.4

Not sure that means anything to you. Sure doesn’t to me, but there you go.

Comment: Also doubleAA has an answer here that tells you more although not much, because there isn’t much  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22930

Comment: That's not my answer, but Michoel's. I just edited it for a typo

Comment: This is brought explicitly in Tanya (I believe it's in chapter 6). Going into iyun when learning that Perek, you might find some explanations regarding the significance of the different parts of that verse and why each one represents a different level of Tum'a/klipaa. I heard a few myself, but I don't want to provide an answer based on feint memory without reviewing my sources first...